# How to set target user's drive of google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried sample code of google drive upload file. I have 2 google account. When I set CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET of account A, it can upload file to account A successfully. However, When I set CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET of account B, it still upload file to account A. How can I set to upload file to account B?

The code is the same as sample code from google. I just replace the CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET and REDIRECT_URI

```
import httplib2
import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

CLIENT_ID = 'My account CLIENT_ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'My account CLIENT_SECRET'

OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

REDIRECT_URI = 'http://lingdisk.synology.me/'

FILENAME = 'Document.txt'

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

media_body = MediaFileUpload(FILENAME, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
body = {
'title': 'My document',
'description': 'A test document',
'mimeType': 'text/plain'
}

file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

It's a stupid error. I save credential and use old credential even I change new CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET and REDIRECT_URI in code.